# ros2 launch fails after following some tutorials

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros2 launch turtlebot3_cartographer cartographer.launch.py works fine.

colcon_cd PACKAGENAME to ~/dev_ws/src/PACKAGENAME works fine.

colcon build --packages-select PACKAGENAME works fine in ~/dev_ws.

I have that in ~/.baschrc

```
export _colcon_cd_root=~/dev_ws
export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=1
export ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
export ROS_VERSION=ros-foxy
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash
source /usr/share/colcon_cd/function/colcon_cd.sh
```

What to check why ros2 launch PACKAGENAME.launch.py would fail ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399032/ros2-launch-fails-after-following-some-tutorials/) by [vKuehn](https://answers.ros.org/users/17921/vkuehn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2022-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

solved..
a package install was missing for one of mine under ~/dev_ws/src.
After installing that ros2 launch works fine
very odd as the missing PACKAGENAME was the one I have created.

---

Originally posted by [vKuehn](https://answers.ros.org/users/17921/vkuehn/) with karma: 116 on 2022-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-14**:
How did you create this package? Maybe you missed a step in its configuration

**Comment by [vKuehn](https://answers.ros.org/users/17921/vkuehn/) on 2022-04-15**:
@ljaniec that is very probably the case. But how to fix such a problem I would have hoped for some hint during the start or a log to look at...

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-15**:
I think [rosdep](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep) should help you here with additional dependencies in your workspace

**Comment by [vKuehn](https://answers.ros.org/users/17921/vkuehn/) on 2022-04-15**:
that's the ros1 documentation. but thanks for the hint

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-15**:
Rosdep is used with ROS2 too: https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html#install-dependencies-using-rosdep, https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/How-To-Guides/Building-a-Custom-Debian-Package.html?highlight=rosdep, https://answers.ros.org/question/310728/rosdep-and-ros2/

**Comment by [vKuehn](https://answers.ros.org/users/17921/vkuehn/) on 2022-04-18**:
thanks for that and keeping answering